# How to update an Outlook appoiment using VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

How can I update/edit existing calendar appointments using VBA? Why does following VBA code fail to update the subject?

**VBA sub:**

```
Sub failToEditAppointment()
    Dim oSession  As Variant
    Set oSession = Application.Session
    Dim oCalendar As Variant
    Set oCalendar = oSession.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    Dim oItems As Variant
    Set oItems = oCalendar.Items
   
    oItems.IncludeRecurrences = False
    oItems.Sort "[Location]"
   
    Debug.Print oItems(1).Subject
    oItems(1).Subject = "foo"
    Debug.Print oItems(1).Subject
    oItems(1).Save
    Debug.Print oItems(1).Subject
End Sub
```

**Output:**

> Valentine's Day
>
> Valentine's Day
>
> Valentine's Day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying and saving different objects - every time you call `oItems.Item(i)`, you get back a brand new COM object that is not guaranteed to know anything about the other instances of that object. Sometimes Outlook caches the last used object, sometimes it does not. Store the item in a dedicated variable. On a more general note, multiple dot notation (like oItem.Item(1)) is always a bad idea.

```
Dim oItem As Object

oItems.IncludeRecurrences = False
oItems.Sort "[Location]"
set oItem  = oItems(1)
Debug.Print oItem.Subject
oItem.Subject = "foo"
Debug.Print oItem.Subject
oItem.Save
Debug.Print oItem.Subject
```

Answer (score 0):

**Seems to work if you set the item to variable of type AppointmentItem.**

```
Sub failToEditAppointment()
    Dim oSession  As Variant
    Set oSession = Application.Session
    Dim oCalendar As Variant
    Set oCalendar = oSession.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    Dim oItems As Variant
    Set oItems = oCalendar.Items
   
    oItems.IncludeRecurrences = False
    oItems.Sort "[Location]"
   
    Dim appointment As AppointmentItem
    Set appointment = oItems(1)
    Debug.Print appointment.Subject
    appointment.Subject = "foo"
    Debug.Print appointment.Subject
    appointment.Save
    Debug.Print appointment.Subject
End Sub
```

**Output:**

> Valentine's Day
>
> foo
>
> foo